# Iniciar consulta a mysql en imput text cuando este esta activo y referenciarlo por si id

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Sigo intentando perfeccionar mi formulario con la función de auto completado.

El código que tengo hasta ahora funciona mediante la opción keydown y necesitaría que se iniciara la consulta a mysql cuando el usuario de el foco al imput text que tiene asignada la consulta y no cuando pulse.
He probado con las opciones "click" "focus" "ready", pero solo aparece el desplegable con la opción keydown.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.nombreccli', function() {
```

Otro problema que tengo es que la función de auto completar busca el imput text mediante su class. Estoy utilizando los estilos de  bootstrap y al tener varias cajas de texto con la función de autocompletar tengo que usar la etiqueta class de estás como id y por lo tanto pierdo el estilo css.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.nombreccli', function() {
```

Muchas gracias,

index.php

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Webslesson Demo - Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >
            <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(document).on('keydown', '.nombrecli', function() {

                    var id = this.id;
                    var splitid = id.split('_');
                    var index = splitid[1];

                    $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0, // <-- AQUI le indicamos que se despliegue sin esperar a que ingresen datos
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "getDetails.php",
                                type: 'post',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    search: request.term,request:1
                                },
                                success: function( data ) {
                                    response( data );
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                            var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                            // AJAX
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'getDetails.php',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success:function(response){

                                    var len = response.length;

                                    if(len > 0){
                                        var idcli = response[0]['idcli'];
                                        var namecli = response[0]['nombrecli'];
                                        var telefonocli = response[0]['telefonocli'];


                                        document.getElementById('nombrecli_'+index).value = namecli;
                                        document.getElementById('telefonocli_'+index).value = telefonocli;


                                    }

                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });


            });



        </script>


        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h2 align="center"><a href="http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/dynamically-add-remove-input-fields-in-php-with-jquery-ajax.html" title="Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</a></h2><br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                                <td colspan="3" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#00CCFF"><b>DATOS DEL CLIENTE</b></td>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>CLIENTE: <input type="text" name="nombrecli_1" placeholder="Enter your Name" id='nombrecli_1' size="25" class="nombrecli" class="form-control name_list1" /></td>
                                    <td>REF. CLIENTE:<input type="text" name="referencia_cliente" placeholder="Introduce la referencía de facturación" id='referencia_cliente'  size="40" class="form-control name_list"" /></td>
                                    <td>Orden:<input type="file" name="ordendecarga" placeholder="Sube la orden de carga" id='ordendecarga'  size="10" class="form-control name_list"" /></td>

                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>




        </body>
    </html>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $('#addcon').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_fieldcon').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>CONTACTO '+i+':<input type="text" name="nombrecon'+i+'" id="nombrecon'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="nombrecon'+i+'" size="25" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="telefonocon'+i+'" id="telefonocon'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="mailcon'+i+'" id="mailcon'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            i--;
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
        });



    });



        $('#submit').click(function(){      
            $.ajax({
                url:"adddataviajes.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para referenciar los imput text por el "id" en vez de por la etiqueta "class" hay que modificar:

```
 $(document).on('keydown', '.nombrecli', function() {
```

por:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#nombrecli', function() {
```